# Expand plot area of grid object to accomodate legend using ggplot2 or grid

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have generated this plot using `fhm <- ChIPpeakAnno::featureAlignedHeatmap(...)` and then saved it using `ggplot2::ggsave(filename = "fn.png", plot = fhm, ...)`
[image: plot]
However, the legend ends up behind the plot. If I increase the `ggsave(..., width, ...)` argument, the legend eventually appears, but the plot is far too wide, all of the individual panels have been stretched horizontally, and the font is tiny:
[image: wide_plot]
Is there a way to edit the `fhm` object to expand the background area without stretching the plot areas?

I'm sure this question has been asked, but I don't think I'm searching with the right terms. Thanks.

EDIT: In case this information is useful, the results of `summary`:

```
> summary(featureheatmap)
      Length Class Mode
 [1,] 5      gTree list
 [2,] 5      gTree list
 [3,] 5      gTree list
 [4,] 5      gTree list
 [5,] 5      gTree list
 [6,] 5      gTree list
 [7,] 5      gTree list
 [8,] 5      gTree list
 [9,] 5      gTree list
[10,] 5      gTree list
[11,] 5      gTree list
[12,] 5      gTree list
[13,] 5      gTree list
[14,] 5      gTree list
[15,] 5      gTree list
[16,] 5      gTree list
[17,] 5      gTree list
[18,] 5      gTree list
[19,] 5      gTree list
[20,] 5      gTree list
[21,] 5      gTree list
[22,] 5      gTree list
[23,] 5      gTree list
[24,] 5      gTree list
[25,] 5      gTree list
[26,] 5      gTree list
> featureheatmap %>% lapply(summary)
[[1]]
              Length Class    Mode     
name           1     -none-   character
gp             0     -none-   NULL     
vp            33     viewport list     
children       1     gList    list     
childrenOrder  1     -none-   character

[[2]]
              Length Class    Mode     
name           1     -none-   character
gp             0     -none-   NULL     
vp            33     viewport list     
children       2     gList    list     
childrenOrder  2     -none-   character

[[3]]
              Length Class    Mode     
name           1     -none-   character
gp             0     -none-   NULL     
vp            33     viewport list     
children       2     gList    list     
childrenOrder  2     -none-   character

[[4]]
              Length Class    Mode     
name           1     -none-   character
gp             0     -none-   NULL     
vp            33     viewport list     
children       2     gList    list     
childrenOrder  2     -none-   character

[[5]]
              Length Class    Mode     
name           1     -none-   character
gp             0     -none-   NULL     
vp            33     viewport list     
children       2     gList    list     
childrenOrder  2     -none-   character

[[6]]
              Length Class    Mode     
name           1     -none-   character
gp             0     -none-   NULL     
vp            33     viewport list     
children       2     gList    list     
childrenOrder  2     -none-   character

[[7]]
              Length Class    Mode     
name           1     -none-   character
gp             0     -none-   NULL     
vp            33     viewport list     
children       2     gList    list     
childrenOrder  2     -none-   character

[[8]]
              Length Class    Mode     
name           1     -none-   character
gp             0     -none-   NULL     
vp            33     viewport list     
children       2     gList    list     
childrenOrder  2     -none-   character

[[9]]
              Length Class    Mode     
name           1     -none-   character
gp             0     -none-   NULL     
vp            33     viewport list     
children       2     gList    list     
childrenOrder  2     -none-   character

[[10]]
              Length Class    Mode     
name           1     -none-   character
gp             0     -none-   NULL     
vp            33     viewport list     
children       2     gList    list     
childrenOrder  2     -none-   character

[[11]]
              Length Class    Mode     
name           1     -none-   character
gp             0     -none-   NULL     
vp            33     viewport list     
children       2     gList    list     
childrenOrder  2     -none-   character

[[12]]
              Length Class    Mode     
name           1     -none-   character
gp             0     -none-   NULL     
vp            33     viewport list     
children       1     gList    list     
childrenOrder  1     -none-   character

[[13]]
              Length Class    Mode     
name           1     -none-   character
gp             0     -none-   NULL     
vp            33     viewport list     
children       2     gList    list     
childrenOrder  2     -none-   character

[[14]]
              Length Class    Mode     
name           1     -none-   character
gp             0     -none-   NULL     
vp            33     viewport list     
children       1     gList    list     
childrenOrder  1     -none-   character

[[15]]
              Length Class    Mode     
name           1     -none-   character
gp             0     -none-   NULL     
vp            33     viewport list     
children       2     gList    list     
childrenOrder  2     -none-   character

[[16]]
              Length Class    Mode     
name           1     -none-   character
gp             0     -none-   NULL     
vp            33     viewport list     
children       1     gList    list     
childrenOrder  1     -none-   character

[[17]]
              Length Class    Mode     
name           1     -none-   character
gp             0     -none-   NULL     
vp            33     viewport list     
children       2     gList    list     
childrenOrder  2     -none-   character

[[18]]
              Length Class    Mode     
name           1     -none-   character
gp             0     -none-   NULL     
vp            33     viewport list     
children       1     gList    list     
childrenOrder  1     -none-   character

[[19]]
              Length Class    Mode     
name           1     -none-   character
gp             0     -none-   NULL     
vp            33     viewport list     
children       2     gList    list     
childrenOrder  2     -none-   character

[[20]]
              Length Class    Mode     
name           1     -none-   character
gp             0     -none-   NULL     
vp            33     viewport list     
children       1     gList    list     
childrenOrder  1     -none-   character

[[21]]
              Length Class    Mode     
name           1     -none-   character
gp             0     -none-   NULL     
vp            33     viewport list     
children       2     gList    list     
childrenOrder  2     -none-   character

[[22]]
              Length Class    Mode     
name           1     -none-   character
gp             0     -none-   NULL     
vp            33     viewport list     
children       1     gList    list     
childrenOrder  1     -none-   character

[[23]]
              Length Class    Mode     
name           1     -none-   character
gp             0     -none-   NULL     
vp            33     viewport list     
children       2     gList    list     
childrenOrder  2     -none-   character

[[24]]
              Length Class    Mode     
name           1     -none-   character
gp             0     -none-   NULL     
vp            33     viewport list     
children       1     gList    list     
childrenOrder  1     -none-   character

[[25]]
              Length Class    Mode     
name           1     -none-   character
gp             0     -none-   NULL     
vp            33     viewport list     
children       2     gList    list     
childrenOrder  2     -none-   character

[[26]]
              Length Class    Mode     
name           1     -none-   character
gp             0     -none-   NULL     
vp            33     viewport list     
children       1     gList    list     
childrenOrder  1     -none-   character
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to give your legend more space on the right margin of your plot, you can specify custom margins for your plot, thus ensuring that there will be empty space on the right side for your legend:

```
plot + 
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0, 40, 0, 0), "mm"))
```

But if the real problem is that your legends are too long, you could also use something like `stringr::str_wrap` to split the string into multiple lines instead of a single, long line.

Comment: When I run `tmp <- fhm + ggplot2::theme(plot.margin = grid::unit(c(0, 40, 0, 0), "mm"))` the object `tmp` is `NULL`. Is your code using a different `unit` function? Thanks.

Comment: I'm using `ggplot2::unit()` but it should work regardless, unless the function you say you used to create the plot (`ChIPpeakAnno::featureAlignedHeatmap`) does something else to the plot object that's not standard.